# C# Entity Framework Linq Join One to Many relationships in many tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Is there a way to bind many to many relationships in multiple tables into one object in C# Linq utilizing the entity framework?

In the Yii framework in php you can join a model with many relationships. Each returns a predefined array of the separate models.

Such as I have multiple sellers who have multiple customers who have multiple sales orders who have multiple sales order items. Is there a way to return 1 Object with all this data together?

Or would it be to split out multiple queries?

Comment: You do not like it to accept answers to your questions, don't you?

Comment: Once I find a solution that works.

Comment: Well, I told you how it works. I answered your question and all follow up questions. I am not gonna write your code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you properly set up the data model, EF will handle this automatically.

Say if you have a many-to-many relationship between tables `People` and `Projects`.  If you create a table called `PeopleProjects` whose only two fields are foreign keys to the two tables, then EF will create a "Projects" collection property on the `People` object, and a "People" collection property on the `Projects" object.

Comment: You still have to "include" the navigation properties that you want to join into your result set, otherwise selecting a single object that has many deep links could result in returning your whole database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure there is not lazy loading involved, this would be the way to go to get all that stuff in one huge object graph:

```
var obj = dbContext.Sellers.Include(
        r => r.Customers.Select(
            r2 => r2.SalesOrders.Select(
                r3 => r3.Items
            )
        )
    ).SingleOrDefault(seller => seller.Id == id)
```

Comment: Can you join tables with the seller? As Well .join(?

Comment: The above statement is the c# EF LINQ way of joining stuff. The resulting SQL will contain joins over all the tables where above types data resides. So there will be one single SQL query with one result set and EF will map it onto your types.

Comment: Remark: "join" is relational lingo, where "include" is the term for object graphs in EF. A include on the object side will result in a join on the relational storage backend.

Comment: Since there are seleveral orders to a customer would it be seller include, customer include, sales order include sales order item select

Comment: No, above code covers that. You can have multiple .Include calls, but you would use it for different paths in your graph. By the way LINQ/EF works, you can not have .Includes within .Includes. Anyway, above code does what you want to do.

Comment: You might also use the non type-safe string pathes as in `var obj = dbContext.Sellers.Include("Customers.SalesOrders.Items")`.

Comment: Please don't use magic strings like that if you can avoid them, the syntax in the answer is the preferred type safe mechanism. if Include via lambda does not work, make sure you have included the using statment for System.Data.Entity

Comment: @demodave yes you can use manual joining statements as well if you need to, that example is a little more complex but can easily be done. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527897/entity-framework-how-to-manually-produce-inner-joins-with-linq-to-entitites